# Possible to use SideCar with MacBook Pro w/ 4 external displays?

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, display, sidecar

As noted in the [tech specs](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP809?locale=en_US) of the MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019), it can support up to four external 4k monitors, and that's how I've set up mine. The maxed-out number of monitors + the laptop's display effectively give me five displays.

Can I use SideCar to add an additional display to this set-up?

> MacBook Pro + SideCar + **4** external displays = **6** displays

Or would SideCar count as one of the 4 external displays?

> MacBook Pro + SideCar + **3** external displays = **5** displays

I don't currently have a compatible iPad to test this with and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere else. I also [posted this question on Apple's discussion forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253542957) but as specific display-related questions seem to get few responses there, I thought I'd try here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this works as a way to get six displays… [jksoegaard's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/434802/64039) was the best confirmation I could find, so I tried it out and can confirm that it works. You can see the iPad in the center of the set up below:

[image: Six-display set-up]

Once you set up the iPad in **System Preferences** > **Sidecar**, you can then arrange the iPad's display just like any other display in **System Preferences** > **Displays** > **Arrangement**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested on the 16-inch MacBook Pro 2019, but it seems to me on my hardware that the SideCar does not count as an external display in this sense. So you should be able to get a total of 6 displays that way!

Comment: That's certainly what I suspected… SideCar is implemented at the OS level (if my understanding is correct), has a completely separate preference pane, and can connect wirelessly, so it would seem that it's not going through the same hardware bottleneck that results in the limitation on the number of displays.